# why the output starts from 402 althoug the initial is zero?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            if (i%2==0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your console won't scroll back far enough, perhaps?

Comment: is there any way that I can see all the output

Comment: Change your console settings. Or pipe the output to a pager, e.g. `./myprogram | less` (if you are on Windows, I don't know if there is something equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

It's start from `0` but you can't see.Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   if (i % 2 == 0)
   {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
   }
   if (i % 100 == 0) Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Press enter to see next numbers.That will show 100 numbers at once,you can change it if you want to display less number..